# Calculating BigO Notation

Tags: encryption, aes, big-o, filesize, memory-efficient

I am doing an experiment for an essay in computer science and my topic is encryption. I want to compare the file sizes of files encrypted using AES Crypt and Blowfish. I need to calculate the BigO for both of these as a requirement for my essay. I am unsure on how to do this, I would much appreciate it if someone could help me.

I also would like some opinions on justification for this topic, i am looking at which algorithm produces the smallest file sizes and to see if the results are linear. I have some justification such as businesses may want to reduce the use of memory and resources, talk about transmission is faster with smaller files and downloading is faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption algorithms such as AES and Blowfish by themselves produces one output byte for each input byte so AES and Blowfish produce the same output sizes.

Except: Both are block based algorithms and depending on the encryption mode the input size may need to be padded to a multiple of the block size so the output is that much larger. For AES the block size is 16-bytes and for Blowfish the block size is 8-bytes so the output may be up to one block size larger than the input.

Try some encryption, there are online tools such as [Online encrypt tool](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/) that support several encryption algorithms. Note: AES is essentially Rijndael-128.

Opinion: There is no justification for this topic, it is well understood and documented, there is essentially no encrypted size reason to choose one over the other. But, Blowfish is not considered as secure as AES so AES should be chosen, even the author of Blowfish states he used AES.

Note: Many CPUs have optimization instructions for AES so AES is in general the best choice.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I understood that cipher text wont be any different in size to the plaintext. I understand that it was just padding. However due to the fact that the padding does add some size to the files when encrypted, I was wanting to investigate this to see if there was any patterns and to see if there was a common ratio between the file size of the plaintext and the ciphertext. Also, I mainly needed help to calculate the BigO for the two algorithms.

Comment: There is a setup time for each encryption, past that the time and computation is essentially linear O(n). The padding (8 or 16 bytes) becones insignificant as the data length increases. All-in-all there is nothing to see here.

Comment: @TreyAesthetics Zaph is correct, the topic you've picked will give you a very boring result.  There are no patterns to padding since it just rounds up to a multiple of 16, and nearly all encryption algorithms operate in O(n).